# Pandas Merge cant merge all columns

Tags: python, pandas, database, merge

I am trying to merge two excels, my data is:
tabla muestra.xlsx

{'Mandante': {0: 400, 1: 400, 2: 400, 3: 400, 4: 400}, 'Usuario': {0: 152163681, 1: '162181297', 2: '144912861', 3: '140752630', 4: '167300316'}, 'Funcion': {0: 'COMPRADOR', 1: 'JEFE DE COMPRAS', 2: 'COMPRADOR', 3: 'COMPRADOR', 4: 'JEFE DE COMPRAS'}, 'Tipo usuario contractual': {0: 'SAP Application Professional', 1: 'SAP Application Professional', 2: 'SAP Application Professional', 3: 'SAP Application Professional', 4: 'SAP Application Professional'}}

and tabla usuarios roles.xlsx

{'Identificación mdte.': {0: 400, 1: 400, 2: 400, 3: 400, 4: 400}, 'Rol': {0: 'SAP_BC_WEBSERVICE_ADMIN', 1: 'SAP_BC_WEBSERVICE_CONSUMER', 2: 'SAP_BC_WEBSERVICE_SERVICE_USER', 3: 'SAP_J2EE_ADMIN', 4: 'SAP_SDCCN_ALL'}, 'Usuario': {0: 'WEBSERVICE', 1: 'WEBSERVICE', 2: 'WEBSERVICE', 3: 'SM_ADMIN_S4P', 4: 'ADMIN_SONDA'}, 'Fecha de inicio': {0: '01.03.2019', 1: '01.03.2019', 2: '01.03.2019', 3: '16.05.2019', 4: '06.08.2019'}, 'Fecha fin': {0: '31.12.9999', 1: '31.12.9999', 2: '31.12.9999', 3: '31.12.9999', 4: '31.12.9999'}, 'Excluido': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}, 'Fecha': {0: '01.03.2019', 1: '01.03.2019', 2: '01.03.2019', 3: '16.05.2019', 4: '06.08.2019'}, 'Hora': {0: datetime.time(16, 11, 6), 1: datetime.time(16, 11, 6), 2: datetime.time(16, 11, 6), 3: datetime.time(15, 27, 30), 4: datetime.time(9, 25, 57)}, 'Cronomarcador UTC en forma breve (AAAAMMDDhhmmss)': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'Org.HR': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}, 'Asign.proviene de rol compuesto': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}}

Using the code

```
# importing the module
import pandas

# reading the files
f1 = pandas.read_excel("~/Desktop/tabla muestra.xlsx")
f2 = pandas.read_excel("~/Desktop/tabla usuarios roles.xlsx")

# merging the files
f3 = f1[["Usuario"]].merge(f2[["Usuario", "Rol"]], 
                                 on = "Usuario", 
                                 how = "outer")

 # creating a new file
 f3.to_excel("~/Desktop/Resultstest5.xlsx", index = False)
```

After the code it returns the following

[image]

I chacked and the ids are on both tables, any clues whats happening?

Comment: Check if you have leading/trailing spaces? If not, provide samples of your data (not screenshots). Include the output of `f1.head().to_dict()` and `f2.head().to_dict()` in your question.

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible sample of a dataset than does not work

Comment: I cuoud change it by erasing the  how = "outer"  part, but now from the original 138 rows I end up with 12 rows. But when I manually check I should have ended up with the 138 rows